# Open local files on Network share with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, iisnode

I've been browsing for hours and I can't find a solution that enables me to open files on a network share in ISSNode.

I've tried using `shelljs` - this works fine when I'm using localhost. But when it is deployed on IIS nothing launches.

I've also tried using the `child_process`.exec. This also works locally but not in production hosted in IIS.

Essentially, I I'm building an internal intranet system for users using Node.js and I need a way to open local network files such xlsx, docx, PDF etc.

Comment: It depends on what problem you hit actually. As the web app is hosted on IIS, the application pool identity is used to access most of the resources, so you need to make sure that account has access to the remote resources (not your own account).

Comment: I changed the application pool to use the administrator account. But that didn’t do anything. I’m not entirely sure how to debug when the app is running on IIS as in I can’t see logs of the issue. :(